# Javascript "Import" Keyword as Used in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular

```
import {Component, View} from "angular2/core";
```

What is the `angular2/core` part here? I thought it was a reference. On checking [mdn on the subject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), I still don't get it, the syntax is clear:

```
import { member1 , member2 } from "module-name";
```

> **module-name**:
>   The name of the module to import. This is a file name.

I don't understand whether or not this is supposed to be a path, which "file name" implies - a js file in an "angular2" folder. It doesn't seem to be, since my angular files are in a 'node_modules' folder and I don't have anything called "angular2" there (I do have something called "@angular" with a "core" folder). If that core folder is it, I don't understand the syntax. Why the "@"? Why not a path? Why does mdn say file-name when it's a folder? Basically, how does this import statement work, exactly?

Another example of this is in a [PLUNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=catalogue) maintained by the angular team (afaik), in app.ts:

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
```

Edit: Adding screenshot - there is some auto-magic going on and I don't understand how it works. IF my file was in "angular2practice" and the import navigated to node_modules/@angular/core - it would make sense. The way it is now...it would have to scan all the parent folders from the file or something. Obviously that's not the case and I am missing something:

[image]

Comment: The MDN is not 100% precise on that: the `ModuleSpecifier` part of the import statement does not have to be a file name, but just some string identifier that the runtime can load.

Comment: Appreciate the reply, but I don't understand where it looks. The js file that uses this imports isn't even in the root for the module being imported. I don't get how the correct file is found.

Comment: I just installed `angular2` module and `core.js` is there right in the module root.

Comment: There *used* to be a folder named `angular2` in early betas of Angular 2, but that has changed. The new folder name is `@angular`, and the correct import statement should read `import {Component, View} from "@angular/core";`.

Comment: @MichaelLiu: The weird part is that it works the way it is, screenshot incoming.

Comment: @VSO: Your screenshot shows the correct import statement. Where do you see `"angular2/core"`?

Comment: @MichaelLiu Right, I confused myself, but I STILL don't get how the pathing works. Maybe I am way overthinking it. Ty for help btw.

Comment: At compile time, the TypeScript compiler uses the file `node_modules\@angular\core\index.d.ts` (essentially building the path using string concatenation). At run time, module loaders handle the resolution of module names, and the precise details depend on the particular loader.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that.

Comment: More info about compile-time module resolution here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Comment: ty //comment length

Comment: @ is [NPM scoped package](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope). `'@angular/core` is package name, while `angular2/core` is the package name plus path (same thing as `angular2/core.ts` or `angular2/core/index.ts`).